# Authentication challenge comes multiple times - iOS8

Tags: ios, ios8

For the same request, the challenge comes multiple times to the "didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge" for Basic and Windows Authentication even though the correct credentials are provided; and this is only with iOS8.

In iOS 7.x the same code snippet works perfectly.

Is there any issue in iOS8 SDK level? Any similar experience?

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Are you talking to IIS?  Does it help if you set header Connection: Keep-Alive?

Comment: If so, how is IIS configured?  Basic & Integrated auth?

Comment: What do you mean by correct credentials?  Are you sending basic auth header with request or do you mean you already auth'd to that callback (which keep alive would affect)

Comment: Yes, I see the same problem.  In fact I receive the authentication challenge endlessly, and although I supply the correct credentials, the challenge is made again and again.

Comment: Figured out when it comes to the basic authentication, the tokens of the authorization header are not identical in versions iOS7 and iOS8. this could be in SDK level. And for windows authentication, when credential persistency is set for the session (NSURLCREdentialPersistenceForSession) it seems to be sorted. But this resides the issue which is a successful login for the wrong credentials until the session is expired.